# I am trying to write a regex for capturing particular word replace it

Tags: python, regex

I'm having following statement ,

```
sentence = " Hi my goal is to achieve highest score in mathematics, but my friend has scored some how more. and now i am myself depressed.
```

I want to replace all "my" with "PRONOUN" as following . I dont want to replace my is myself want to keep myself as it is

Expected Output is :

```
Hi PRONOUN goal is to achieve highest score in mathematics, but PRONOUN friend has scored some how more. and now i am myself depressed.
```

I have tried following regex in python

```
 regex = re.sub(r'\\bmy$')
```

Comment: `re.sub(r'\bmy\b', "PRONOUN")` ?

Comment: Why use `regex`? You can simply using `sentence.replace("my","PRONOUN")`

Comment: Does this have to be in Regex? Could you not use the replace method: `str.replace("my", "PRONOUN")`

Comment: need to do it using regex , to know various regex delimeters

Comment: @Rakesh I tried this but this only replaced the first occurence

Comment: @SayliJawale. What do you mean by only first occurrence?

Comment: @Rakesh Sorry I got it I was not using word boundary at last so it was happening. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are very close. Use boundary at start and end.

**Ex:**

```
import re

sentence = "Hi my goal is to achieve highest score in mathematics, but my friend has scored some how more. and now i am myself depressed."
print(re.sub(r'\bmy\b', "PRONOUN", sentence))
```

**Output:**

```
Hi PRONOUN goal is to achieve highest score in mathematics, but PRONOUN friend has scored some how more. and now i am myself depressed.
```